# If my repository uses a MIT license, can I submit a DMCA takedown for someone who copied it?

Tags: licensing, mit, copyright, dmca

I have an MIT-licensed repository which has been copied entirely, just replacing the author's name. I've heard that MIT takes away most copyright and permits free use, but if anyone can copy code and even just replace my name with theirs, what is the point of the MIT License?

Can I submit a DMCA takedown notice (to GitHub) in my case? Do I even need a lawyer for this? As a student, I can't afford to and I cannot even allow such copying. This discourages open source developers.

Comment: if you do not want to allow copying, what is the reason the repository is licensed under MIT in the first place?

Comment: If developers are discouraged by other people copying their code, then they are not open source developers.

Comment: Can you show which repos are involved? Are the specific changes to the licenses, copyright, or code germane to getting OP an accurate answer?

Comment: @lucidbrot Beacause I want people can copy and improve it, but obviously just copying and replacing author name isn't expected. I would be happy if he/she at least made some improvements and then call himself an author, but he didn't. It's just a copy paste and taking credit

Comment: @MichaelKay I obviously allow copying but I just want a little attribution and improvements, none likes just copy-paste and replacing author name

Comment: Those two repositories don't appear to be forks or copies of one another.

Comment: @AdamBarnes Check the main files [original](https://github.com/jaykali/maskphish/blob/master/maskphish.sh) and [stolen](https://github.com/OnlineHacKing/Masking-URL/blob/main/Masking-OH.sh)

Comment: Aah I see it now.  Consider adding those four links to the opening post, as the derivative repo has removed the MIT license which is against the terms of license and indeed lets you slap it down.

Comment: @AdamBarnes There are little differences as the original one is maintained and updated but still anyone can easily realize which is copied. But these are just example and actual person also did almost the same just replacing my name from LICENSE. I do not own any of the example repo. Should I add this example to main post?

Comment: The key point is that the license has been altered, see Philip Kendall's excellent answer.

Comment: Note that plagiarism is also a separate thing from copyright.  e.g. it's still plagiarism to publish a copy of Hamlet with your name as the author, even though the text itself is in the public domain and thus not protected by any copyright.  (I'm not sure if there's any legal remedy for pure plagiarism that doesn't violate a copyright law, but name and shame is likely to be effective if the offender has any reputation they care about.)

Comment: @PeterCordes But my repo contains a LICENSE which is a "copyright notice", hence I think it is related to copyright

Comment: Yes, I know. There's *also* a copyright violation if they didn't follow the licence.  (i.e. changing your name in the license notice itself, case 1 in Philip's answer, unlike case 2 which is only plagiarism.)  I think Philip's answer is fully correct, but be sure to read it carefully.

Comment: Note that generally its good practice (but not required) to add the licence header to every file covered by the licence. This helps to keep the licence information intact even if a single file is copied from a larger repository

Comment: @user18915229 It's good to be crystal clear about the relationship between a license and copyright. Copying your work is unlawful under copyright laws unless there is a license that permits it; if the license imposes conditions and they aren't in compliance with those conditions, then the license doesn't permit it and therefore the copying is a breach of copyright.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> I've heard that MIT takes away most copyright

This is absolutely not correct; the MIT License (and all other open source licenses) rely on copyright law to be effective.

> and permits free use

The MIT License permits use only within the conditions specified in the license. While that means you can do it without spending money, it is inaccurate to describe it as "free" (particularly within the open source community where "free" is an overloaded term).

Coming back to the point in hand:

> I have a MIT licensed repository which is entirely copied just replacing the author name

The question here is *exactly* what did they do? The requirement in the MIT License is not very long ("The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software."). Therefore:

- If they replaced your name *specifically in the copyright notice*, then they are in violation of the license and you would be able to submit a claim against them.
- If they replaced your name anywhere else (e.g. there was a bit of text in the program which says "This software was written by the great programmer user18915229" and they changed it to "This software was written by the great programmer SomeOtherPerson"), that is absolutely fine - at least legally. Ethically it's questionable, but that's out of scope here.

Comment: "it is inaccurate to describe it as free" - I agree that "free" is an overloaded term in the open source community, but the MIT license fits all the definitions of free that I am aware of (free of cost, freedom to use for whatever, freedom to modify, free to include in open source and commercial software)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135861/discussion-on-answer-by-philip-kendall-is-dmca-takedown-applicable-for-mit-licen).  Please, please don't start new discussions here; they'll be deleted.  If you have a *question* for the author of the answer, then it may be a legitimate comment; otherwise, it's probably not.

Comment: The ethical issue you mention has a specific name: **plagiarism**.  That's a separate thing from copyright.  e.g. it's still plagiarism to publish a copy of Hamlet with your name as the author, even though the text itself is in the public domain and thus not protected by any copyright.  (I'm not sure if there's any legal remedy for pure plagiarism that doesn't violate a copyright law, but name and shame is likely to be effective if the offender has any reputation they care about. )

Comment: In your second example, "*"This software was written by the great programmer SomeOtherPerson"* would be plagiarism unless "this software" is now a much larger work that merely includes all the code from the original, plus a bunch that they did write.  (And it's clear from context that they only mean the software as a whole, not the contents of this copied and slightly-changed file.)

Comment: @PeterCordes There's the concept of moral rights, one of which is the right of attribution/paternity. Removing or replacing the author's name *could* infringe on it. In civil law jurisdictions that right is usually perpetual and inalienable, so likely yes. Otherwise, it depends.

Comment: @AmiralPatate: Ah right, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_rights mentions some countries include moral rights as part of their copyright law.  This would still be separate from the license itself, but might give you a legal mechanism to go after someone.

Comment: Free has one meaning: Freedom. Sometimes English speakers abbreviate "Free of charge", to "Free". But this is an abbreviation, in the same way as half 5 is an abbreviation of half past five (or half to five, in some other languages).

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned earlier, I would strongly suggest that you reach out to the offending party. If they literally took credit for your work and have been "caught red-handed", they are likely to remedy the problem quickly and without you needing to resort to legal remedies. I would suggest creating an issue in the offending github repository and perhaps even a PR correcting the attributions.

The latter has the advantage of creating a record or your requested changes and could help you build a copywrite claim if necessary. It also exposes the potential plagiarism to the community in which the offending code is being used. In other words, start small and escalate as necessary.